# Rails 4: How to add ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES on Ubuntu 14.04 using RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, capistrano, passenger, ubuntu-14.04

Right now I'm trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails app to a Virtual Machine on Windows Azure running Ubuntu but I can fix de set environment variables error as below describe.

I have done added variables to my `.bashrc` and now in  `/etc/environment` but the error is the same:

```
App 1227 stderr: [ 2015-10-06 04:10:57.3814 1352/0x9020d38(Worker 1) utils.rb:86 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_to$
App 1227 stderr: from /home/deploy/apps/matching_people/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_$
App 1227 stderr:        from /home/deploy/apps/matching_people/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
App 1227 stderr:        from /home/deploy/apps/matching_people/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
App 1227 stderr:        from /home/deploy/apps/matching_people/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
App 1227 stderr:        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in `process_request'
App 1227 stderr:        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:151:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 1227 stderr:        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:112:in `main_loop'
App 1227 stderr:        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
App 1227 stderr:        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:112:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
[ 2015-10-06 04:10:57.3819 988/b5efeb40 age/Cor/Req/Utils.cpp:95 ]: [Client 1-1] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
```

This is my `sudo nano /etc/environment` file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

export SECRET_KEY_BASE=2da0d3f0bfd7b9b05110bfad512f42df2d2bb2ef715c4e831caba96a9c0b2141fbfa718dff2f5daf916cd70a70afd1f24df49884c561fbbaf364b36652b2c7d1
ruby -e 'p ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]'

export MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=2015deployer
ruby -e 'p ENV["MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD"]'
```

And when I run `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` or `echo $MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD` I got the exact data.

```
deploy@vmw-ubuserver:~$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
2da0d3f0bfd7b9b05110bfad512f42df2d2bb2ef715c4e831caba96a9c0b2141fbfa718dff2f5daf916cd70a70afd1f24df49884c561fbbaf364b36652b2c7d1

deploy@vmw-ubuserver:~$ echo $MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD
2015deployer
```

But I still getting the same error in production, I'm using RVM, Capistrano, Passenger and NGINX on Ubuntu 14.04.

My database.yml :

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  database: matchpeople_production
  username: deployer
  password: <%= ENV['MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

My secrets.yml :

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Any kind of help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking and looking for the correct answer I have been trying too many options but I didn't make it works fine.

So, suddenly I found I solution while I was testing some configurations found on google.

It is simple, just:

- Add the next lines:

  ```
  export SECRET_KEY_BASE=3aa7e349bh345h245hi23452345h234ih52i3u45h$
  export MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=your_pass_here

  # Uncomment these lines and restart the server to validate if the variables are read correctly
  #ruby -e 'p ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]'
  #ruby -e 'p ENV["MATCH_PEOPLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD"]'
  ```

At the end of the files below:

1. **`sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`**
2. **`sudo nano /etc/environment`**

If you want you can uncomment the last two lines in ***`~/.bash_profile`*** and restart your server and when you login to it again, you will see the value of the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES before your promt as in the picture below.

[image]

I recommend you to keep those lines commented do it just for validate and then comment them again.

If you have any question, please leave a comment!

Hope it could be useful.

Comment: people generally contact people with questions down here, to aid this community. Not through twitter

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there is no secret_token needed in secrets.yml for Ruby RVM.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I think to solve the problem, remove the second line  from your `production:` section

---

In case you need to **add environment variables to RVM**, edit

```
# /etc/profile.d/appspecific.sh
```

add something like

```
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
```

Good luck!

Comment: All right thank you so much! I will try to do this and tell you what's going on! @Val Asensio

Comment: @Lexynux How did it go?

Comment: I found another solution in order to solve this problema, all you need to do is to add some variables to your bash_profile and to environment variables.  I will post it in the next days!

Comment: Did you ever post that @Lexynux?

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood you can see the answer above! I hope it could be useful